# nginx - proxy_pass with variable as hostname points all queries to index.html

Tags: variables, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have an nginx reverse proxy proxying everything under `/docs` to another nginx instance (on `/`). This other instance responds to DNS name `wiki-pages`. Both instances run in Docker. When I hardcode the DNS name like `proxy_pass http://wiki-pages:80/;`, it works perfectly.

`nginx: v1.21.0`, build detailed below.

**Initial problem**: a non-resolvable DNS name prevents nginx to start.

**Workaround**: I do a DNS resolution in my `location` block, so the reverse proxy can start even if the `wiki-pages` site is down.

---

## **Blocking problem**

When I use `proxy_pass` with the hardcoded DNS name (`wiki-pages`), it works perfectly. When I use `set $target http://wiki-pages:80/;` and `proxy_pass $target;`, ALL files queried are returning the content of `/index.html` (on `wiki-pages`), with `Content-Type: text/html`. Status code: `200`.

> The complete server block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.mysite.com;

    # Redirect everything to HTTPS
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    server_name www.mysite.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl_certificate     /ssl/live/www.mysite.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/live/www.mysite.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

    location / {
    }

    location /docs {
        # Add trailing / when needed
        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

        resolver 127.0.0.11;
        set $target http://wiki-pages:80/;
        proxy_pass  $target;
    }
}
```

> I tried this:

```
location /docs {
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    set $target wiki-pages;
    proxy_pass  http://$target:80/;
}
```

> The following block works perfectly (no variable)

```
location /docs {
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    proxy_pass http://wiki-pages:80/;
}
```

I also tried a bunch of proxy headers changes, played with trailing `/` (in the `location` parameter, in the `proxy_pass` uri), played with `$uri`, `$request_uri`, etc. Same behavior, all queries are returning the content of `/index.html`.

---

Interestingly, if I create a symlink `docs -> ./` in my `wiki-pages` site root dir, the following block works as intended:

```
location /docs {
    # Add trailing / when needed
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    set $target http://wiki-pages:80/;
    proxy_pass  $target$request_uri;
}
```

**However, I'd like to avoid creating this symlink.**

---

I don't know what to try now. `nginx-debug` did not show anything interesting, only `200` responses, yet all queries are returning the same content...

I really don't understand how `proxy_pass` does work, and why replacing a hardcoded value `abc` by a variable with the *same* hardcoded value `abc` changes the behavior.

---

**Questions**:

- **How** to accomplish what I'm trying to do? e.g:

  - Having my reverse-proxy starting even if my backend DNS name is not resolvable
  - Using `proxy_pass` with a variable as the target, and getting the same behavior than with a hardcoded value
- **Why** `proxy_pass` behaves like that?

Please, let me know if you need any more information.

---

> nginx version/build

```sh
root@reverse-proxy:/# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.21.0
built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.21.0/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.21.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'

root@reverse-proxy:/# nginx-debug -V
nginx version: nginx/1.21.0
built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.21.0/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.21.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie' --with-debug
```